# I am working on an assignment about ordered list in java. We're not allowed to use sort so I made a solution but 2 numbers are outputted twice

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

here's the code for MyArrayList

```
public void addLast(int number){
    if(!isFull())
        doubleTheArray();
        element[count++] = number;
}
```

and here's the code for MyOrderedList

```
public void add(int item){
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

        for(int j = i+1; j < count; j++){

            if(element[i] > element[j]){
                item = element[i];
                element[i] = element[j];
                element[j] = item; 
            }
        }
    }

    addLast(item);            
}
```

This is the main method

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    MyOrderedList oList = new MyOrderedList();

    oList.add(3);
    oList.add(5);
    oList.add(2);
    oList.add(4);
    oList.add(7);
    oList.add(8);
    oList.add(10);
    System.out.println("Ordered list of items: "+ oList);
}
```

Can anyone help me find out what's wrong? We're not allowed to use sort so I made a solution but 2 numbers are outputted twice in the main method for MyOrderedList. We have to add the elements at the right location. Or in ascending order for add(item). isFull() is boolean method that doubles (doubleTheArray()) the array size if it is true.

Comment: `add` may overwrite `item` when swapping elements.

Comment: I would suggest debugging to learn where your problem is, but as @ScottHunter says item is overridden straight away

Comment: Also, when adding an item into `OrderedList` should not you keep it sorted and use binary search to identify the position where to insert the new `item`?  In current implementation you always re-sort the list when adding an element.

Comment: If you *want* `add` to change `item` to be the value that goes at the end (which your call to `addLast` suggests), then your loop should be inserting `item` into the list where it needs to go, swapping it with the value currently in that position, and doing that across the list.

Comment: @AlexRudenko So I should use another method that inserts the items instead of using the addLast()?

Comment: `addLast` only makes sense when you are adding a value no smaller than all currently in the list.

Comment: Note that `add` will not swap *anything* if the list is properly sorted, and will add the new value to the end, regardless of where it *should* go.    As @Byron says, debugging would have sown you this.